# ¿ Cómo saber cuando la señal del celular es baja cuando se está online?

Tags: javascript, pwa

Estoy haciendo una PWA para celular y gracias a navigator.onLine detecto cuando estoy en linea o no, pero me provoca problemas cuando está online pero la señal celular es muy baja, ya que se demora mucho en actualizar las tablas indexeddb.

**¿Cómo detectar que la señal del celular es baja cuando se está online?.**

Comment: Podrías revisar [NetworkInformation Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation) como una posibilidad. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te invitamos a revisar [ask] para que conozcas como realizar preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Hay una API en el navegador que se llama NETWORK que provee información de la red del navegador. La disponibilidad de la misma es relativa al dispositivo y la marca del navegador. Podes saber que tipo de conexión tiene el usuario y la ultima velocidad de descarga. Te dejo aca un ejemplo de como usarla:

```js
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection || navigator.msConnection;
    if (connection) {
        var data = {
            saveData: connection.saveData,
            downlink: connection.downlink, //velocidad descarga MB
            downlinkMax: connection.downlinkMax, //Maxima velocidad descarga MB
            type: ((connection.type !== undefined && connection.type !== null) ? connection.type : ""), //tipo de conexion ej: wifi, 3g, lte etc.
            effectiveType: (connection.type !== connection.effectiveType && connection.effectiveType !== null) ? connection.effectiveType : "", //tipo de conexion efectiva.
            rtt: connection.rtt //tiempo rtt.
        };

        function updateConnectionStatus() {
            console.log("La conexion ha cambiado de " + data.type + " a " + connection.effectiveType);
            data.type = connection.effectiveType;
        }
        //Podes agregar un evento para detectar cuando la conexion ha cambiado.
        connection.addEventListener('change', updateConnectionStatus);
        console.log(data);
    } else {

        console.log("Navegador no soporta api NETWORK");
    }
```

Comment: gracias por tu contribucion, recuerda ayudar a la persona que pregunta a mejorar su pregunta en base a [ask], ayudanos a mantener la calidad en el sitio, saludos.